# How to stop window size jumping around when forcing fixed aspect ratio?

Tags: qt, window, qml, qtquick2, aspect-ratio

Here's my test code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    readonly property int defaultWidth: 700
    readonly property int defaultHeight: 500
    width: defaultWidth
    height: defaultHeight

    readonly property real aspectRatio: defaultWidth / defaultHeight
    readonly property real scaleFactor: width / defaultWidth

    onWidthChanged: {
        var properHeight = Math.round(width / aspectRatio);
        if ( height !== properHeight ) {
            height = properHeight
        }
    }
    onHeightChanged: {
        var properWidth = Math.round(height * aspectRatio);
        if ( width !== properWidth ) {
            width = properWidth
        }
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit
        text: "Lorem ipsum"
        font.pixelSize: 40 * scaleFactor
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

It implements fixed aspect ratio, but it doesn't work very well: there is sort of flicker (window size jumping between the fixed-aspect-ratio size and the mouse-resized size), and it may adjust wrong dimension depending on order of width and height change events. In effect, when size is adjusted programmatically, the window edge may start jumping between mouse cursor position and programmatically set, different position.

What should happen is, the window edge which is dragged should follow mouse cursor (like in any resize), and the other edges should change to maintain aspect ratio:

- If user drags left/right edge, bottom edge should move to maintain aspect ratio.
- If user drags top/bottom edge, then right edge should also move to maintain aspect ratio.
- When user drags a corner, there are two possible sizes to take to keep the aspect ratio, as either height or width could be changed programmatically. How exactly to determine this doesn't matter, as long as it is consistent.
- It is ok, if aspect ratio is fixed only after resizing stops, though real-time would be better. But how to reliably detect when resizing actually stops?
- If this can't be done with Qt alone, I'm interested in both Windows and X11/Linux specific solutions.

**How to achieve the resize while preserving aspect ratio, using native window resize controls** (normal window borders or whatever the platform uses), so that it behaves logically and looks nice **?**

---

Edit, "hint": I had time to do some research, overriding `QQuickView::resizeEvent` and calling `resize` from there seems to be able to do the trick, but I didn't have time to get it to work quite right yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a problem like that once, I ended up a "chicken or egg" paradox, so I disabled the window decorations altogether and made custom resizing bars. This established a proper value flow from handles to dimensions, without it the flow was dimensions to dimensions, if that makes any sense...

If removing the window frame is not a problem for you, you could go that way, for me it wasn't since I was looking for a custom and platform independent look, so the window frame was actually part of the application:

```
Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 250
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window

    MouseArea {
      width: 20
      height: 20
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
      anchors.right: parent.right
      onPositionChanged: {
        var w = mouseX + x, h = mouseY + y
        if (w > (h * 2)) {
          main.width = w
          main.height = w * .5
        } else {
          main.height = h
          main.width = h * 2
        }
      }
      Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
      }
    }
}
```

That's just a trivial example, obviously in a complete solution you should do all sides and corners. Aspect ratio is fixed at 2/1.

On my system there is still some flickering for the entire window, but I think that's just the scenegraph, but the "dimensions jumping around" problem is effectively solved.

EDIT:

To clarify, what I mean by the "flow was dimensions to dimensions" is that the handles manipulate the dimensions, and you hook to the `changed` handlers to... make a change. I suspect that's why it works so flaky. If so, in order to employ the window frame for resizing, the connection between the handles and the window dimensions has to be severed to insert the aspect ratio code between. Unfortunately, filtering out the resize event at `QGuiApplication` level did not prevent the resizing, but maybe there is another way to do that, for example overriding the class.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think I'll want to keep the frame, but I might do something similar to to you: disallow normal resizing, and just have toggleable "normal size" and "maximized size", instead of my own resizing handle. Still, I hope someone answers with a full solution.

Comment: Alas, filtering out the resize event doesn't prevent the window from resizing as I thought it would.

Comment: It seems you can stop resizinging by setting maximum and minimum height and width to allow only one size.

Comment: Stopping resizing isn't the problem, its reusing the windows frame resize bars with custom aspect ratio. There is more than one way to disable resizing and keep the windows frame, however once disabled, the resize handles stop responding to user input and can't be interacted with.

Comment: @hyde - At this point it doesn't look like the problem can be solved from QML, not even from C++ alone, not without overriding the window class at private api level. It looks like one of those many design limitations in Qt I told you about in that chat session, the behavior is static and fixed, and the code to override is in the most inconvenient and problematic place to modify.

Comment: I'm actually thinking of detecting if user starts resizing horizontally or vertically, and then controlling the other dimension with minimum/maximum properties... Hacky, and probalby will not work quite nicely anyway, but I think there's a chance it will be ok. I suppose I'll try myself after the bounty expires, if nobody is greedy enough to do it for 100 Internet Points :)

Comment: You will likely still have problems with the user uses a corner to modify both at the same time, and dunno about others, but I personally mostly use the corners. The only solution I could thing of so far that has decent chance to work well involves changing the Qt code, which is not ideal. The very least you must make your override class a friend in order to get access to the window "privates". Extending the class alone is not an option as all of the needed functionality is either private functions or the private pimpl. Now if they just left those protected... but alas, that's Qt for you ;)

Comment: Yeah, corners would be tricky, I guess one way would be to lock the resize direction when starting resize from corner, based on which way user moves the mouse most. But I think subclassing `QQuickView` (ie. not using QML `Window`) and overriding `resizeEvent` should be able to do the trick. One more thing to try I suppose.

Comment: "should be able to do the trick" - that seems unlikely, both the view and the window resize events just call pimpl functions.

Comment: Got some time for testing. Just simply overriding `QQuickView::resizeEvent` enables a working resize (there is some flicker on Win10 at least) by letting one dimension be adjusted by user, and then the other dimension is maintained at given aspect ratio. Of course this leaves either horizontal or vertical edge resize non-working (because that direction is locked to the other dimension and not directly user adjustable, so dragging that edge has 0 effect). I think it'll be necessary to get global mouse coordinates relative to window corner to make everything work. Maybe later...

Comment: Also, bounty expired, so here you are, even if your solution isn't exactly what I was after :). I'll still leave the question open, though.

Comment: @hyde - thanks, although I did answer before the bounty was issued. But maybe now you see what I meant - 1.5 gb worth of source code, and not only it lacks a very simple, obvious and useful feature, but it also makes it ridiculously problematic to implement it yourself.

Comment: Well, using `QCursor::pos()` allows making a version which works quite nicely. However, it still flickers, and fixing that might require hacking Qt itself. But Qt development is community driven in large part, so the feature is missing at least partly, because nobody thought it'd be valuable enough to implement. Of course every new feature (including this one) is more bloat...

Comment: @hyde - now that's whitewashing it, implying that Qt's bloat is because of too many features :D Most of it is core repetition, wheels reinventing and way too many poor design fix-ups. About being "community driven" - that really sounds great, I've also heard that bug reporting is important and repeatedly encouraged to do so every time I find a problem, yet none of the bugs I reported has been addressed so far, not even the critical ones. Your dedication however is admirable, even if IMO very much undeserved. But maybe it is a problem with my own expectations as a perfectionist.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's one possible workaround. It doesn't try to control the window size, but instead adds extra item inside the window, which then contains the rest of the UI, and keeps the desired aspect ratio: If window aspect ratio is different, then there's empty area either above and below, or left and right, of the content area, drawn with window color ("gray" here). The content area is filled with "yellow" here to show the difference.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {

    readonly property int defaultWidth: 700
    readonly property int defaultHeight: 500
    readonly property real defaultAspectRatio: defaultWidth / defaultHeight

    readonly property real aspectRatio: width / height
    readonly property real scaleFactor: content.width / defaultWidth

    visible: true
    width: defaultWidth
    height: defaultHeight
    color: "gray"

    Item {
        id: content
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: (aspectRatio > defaultAspectRatio)
               ? parent.height * defaultAspectRatio
               : parent.width
        height: (aspectRatio < defaultAspectRatio)
                ? parent.width / defaultAspectRatio
                : parent.height

        Rectangle { color: "yellow"; anchors.fill: parent } // just to show the effect

        TextEdit {
            clip: true // text drawing needs to be clipped explicitly
            id: textEdit
            text: "Lorem ipsum"
            font.pixelSize: 40 * scaleFactor
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

But this is just a workaround, not a full solution asked for in the question, so the question remains open.